# Why is there a need for design science in a computer science department?

Tags: computer-science

Recently, "design science" has become a popular term in my university department, which is a department of computer science. For example, many current PhD students write in their theses that they are adopting a design science paradigm, typically referring to Herbert Simon's "The Sciences of the Artificial (1970), and Peffers et al. "A Design Science Research Methodology for Information Systems Research" (2007), among others. Why is there a need for using the term "design science" in a computer science department? Isn't computer science in itself enough? Is this a trend among other computer science departments, or is it confined to my own department only?

Comment: This might be a case of different cultures between fields, but do people really "adopt a paradigm" in their serious research papers?

Comment: Are they truly referring to a specific paradigm, one that other researchers may not follow? If so, then the term seems entirely appropriate. If they simply mean "I'm doing computer science", and there would be no loss of information in the new sentence, then no, that seems unnecessary.